# Project on SMS Server

Tags: c#, network-programming, gsm

Hello 
      I have taken a project 'SMS server'---which will do
A. Auto SMS generator for clients like on a specific event like transaction on user account or regular interval like everyday once for reservation status
B. Response receiver for polling through mobile phone.

i was searched a ozeki server but it is not which i want. I want to implement my own SMS server. I am so confused.
So i have no idea how can i implement this project using C#.

Thanks..!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I successfully implemented an SMS server a long time ago...   it is very complicated.

Some of the points you need to consider are:

- You need to find and learn the PDU format, which is the structure of SMS messages on the network
- You need to open a special SMPP account with a cell phone provider.  This can be quite complicated and expensive.
- You need dedicated VPN hardware to connect to the cell phone provider's network.  Software VPN's won't work because the provider probably won't allow Split Tunnelling.  I used a PIX 501.

THEN you can start working on the message tracking, account management, disaster mitigation, etc. etc.

If I started again, I would almost definately find an online SMS gateway provider that has Webservice APIs or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck implementing your "own" SMS gateway. Your best bet is to use an API driven utility model SMS gateway like Twilio.com. They already have REST API's ready to integrate into your application.

Your other options are writing something in C# to interface with a serial port on the computer that would be connected to a GSM modem. The GSM modem acts like a phone on the cell network but accepts modem AT commands and can deliver SMS messages to other phones.

You can also use something like Kannel (open source SMPP gateway) to link up to a 3rd party SMS gateway that talks SMPP like Mblox.com. However you will be paying a lot for something like this.

My guess is you want what Twilio does already.